# @value annotation returns me a wrong value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

When accessing a property with value 7777 @value annotation returns me 20080

**code used**:

- Property in .properties file 
  `proxy.port=7777`
- Variable in java class as

```
    @Value(value = "${proxy.port:0}")
    private Integer proxyPort;
```

is it changing the number base or something ?

Additional information: On eclipse the value is 7777 , when I deploy this on a server the value changes . On server I run it in a jar .

Comment: Why not just putting ```"${proxy.port}")``` ? why adding ```:0``` ?

Comment: Maybe you have different props for different profiles? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: adding  :0 as default. and yes I checked the profile, its correct . only difference it when I run in Eclipse it works . But on my server when deploy as jar it doesn't . any clues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that on server there might be an environment variable that could have different value. Spring treats those at highest preference over values defined in property. Check on your server, if there is a environment variable defined with the same name.

Comment: yes, this is set as env property at root level on the server. I simply changed the properly name to sfprop.proxy and it works as expected :D, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use

```
@Value("${proxy.port}")
```

or with default

```
@Value("${proxy.port:0}")
```

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/9466638/eugene-kortov mentioned, please also check profile specific properties files.

Comment: no,doesnot work.yeah i check the property files are correct used.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting properties from inside `application.yml` as opposed to `application.properties`